# Is mean pairwise distance a metric over subsets of a metric space.

Tags: metric-spaces, discrete-geometry

Specifically, I am looking at finite subsets of a set that is a discrete metric space under [Jaccard Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index). I'm having trouble proving the triangle inequality or coming up with a counterexample.

In the case that it is not, and I'm overlooking some obvious counterexample, does anyone know of a metric that would accurately capture the similarity of these sets (Note, I am NOT looking for Hausdorff distance, as it deals with extrema, which doesn't capture the subtleties of my dataset).

Comment: The question is unclear. Are you asking if the Jaccard distance is a metric, or are you looking for a distance function between finite subsets of a metric space (where your metric space just happens to be a set of subsets of a set using the Jaccard distance as a metric)?

Comment: Distance function between finite subsets of a metric space. Rereading it I can see how the parsing is a little awkward. An example would be the Hausdorff metric, but I am looking for one that behaves more like mean pairwise distance in that it takes average behaviour into account more than extrema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I get you right, for $X$ a metric space with metric $d(x,y)$, define $D(U,V)$ for non-empty finite subsets $U,V\subset X$ by
$$
D(U,V)=\frac{1}{|U|\cdot|V|}\sum_{u\in U,\,v\in V}d(u,v).
$$
A metric would require $D(U,U)=0$, but if $|U|>1$ we get $D(U,U)>0$, so this is not a metric.

However, you specifically ask if the triangle inequality $D(U,V)+D(U,V)\ge D(U,W)$ is true. It is for the simple reason that
$$
D(U,V)+D(V,W)=\tfrac{1}{|U|\cdot|V|\cdot|W|}\sum_{u,v,w}d(u,v)+d(v,w)
\ge\tfrac{1}{|U|\cdot|V|\cdot|W|}\sum_{u,v,w}d(u,w)=D(U,W)
$$
where $u\in U$, $v\in V$, and $w\in W$.

I don't see any quick fix of this to get a metric with $D(U,U)=0$. If I try defining a new distance function $d_D(U,V)=2D(U,V)-D(U,U)-D(V,V)$, you may get $d_D(U,V)<0$ which is even worse.

Comment: I didn't notice that you can collapse the summations like that (since there are $|V|$ of each $(u,v)$ pair and $|W|$ copies of each $(v,w)$ pair). Very cool. 

As for the identity requirement, I'm actually implementing this for a machine learning application and it's not at all a problem to do identity testing separately.